# Where to hook into Json.Net for Custom String Validation based on C# Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, validation, attributes, json.net

Json.Net has many extensibility points. I have a hard time finding the right one for my case.

I receive Json Documents and I want to validate the contents of string values for invalid (Internal Business Rule) content. The values to check are decorated with Attributes. For various reasons i have to do it through Json.Net and not after Json.Net deserialized the value. It has to happen during the deserialization.

That's the example C# Class:

```
public class Echo
{
    public string val1 { get; set; }

    public string val2 { get; set; }

    [AllowJavaScript]
    public string val3 { get; set; }
}
```

That's an example Json Fragment:

```
{
    val1: "foo",
    val2: "bar",
    val3: "alert();"
}
```